# getting "Stack Level Too Deep Error " in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get `Stack Level Too Deep Error`  when i call vendor.account_owner in the `index.html.erb`

the vendor migration file looks like this

```
class CreateVendors < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :vendors, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :website
      t.references :account_owner, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }, type: :uuid
      t.jsonb :data_classification, default: '{}', null: false
      t.integer :auth_type, default: 0
      t.integer :risk, default: 1
      t.datetime :engagement_date
      t.datetime :last_review_date
      t.boolean :is_active, default: true
    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

the Vendor model looks like this

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :data_classification, :employee_data, :corporate_data, :customer_data, :personal_data, :healthcare_data, :payments_data
 
  enum :auth_type, { Unknown: 0, SSO: 1, Password: 2 }
  enum :risk, { Low: 0, Medium: 1, High: 2 }

  belongs_to :account_owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :documents, as: :documentable


  def account_owner 
    account_owner.first_name
  end
end
```

while the User model looks like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  ...
  has_many :authored_policies, class_name: 'Policy', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :created_groups, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :vendors, foreign_key: 'account_owner_id'
    

  
  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

I have checked a similar error  message on the platform but it doesn't address this particular situation
I'll need help as I believe I am probably missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Vendor` class has this:

```rb
def account_owner 
  account_owner.first_name
end
```

1. This method is recursively calling itself over and over again which is leading to the `Stack Level Too Deep Error` because it will never terminate.
2. This method is overriding the `belongs_to :account_owner ...` association you defined a few lines above it.

Try giving it a different name like:

```rb
def account_owner_first_name
  account_owner.first_name
end
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. How could I have missed it. I am grateful

Comment: Alternatively there's `delegate :first_name, to: :account_owner, prefix: true` which will give you a `account_owner_first_name` method, see [`delegate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate).